Unable to decrypt .rpmsg file using SDK version 1.14.128
I am trying to decrypt a .rpmsg file attached to an encrypted Microsoft 365 email. I have found sample code in the Win32 MIP SDK download that can decrypt a .rpmsg file and works successfully in Windows.
I have downloaded and integrated the same MIP SDK version for Android into a test Android application I have created. The Kotlin code is calling into C++ code through JNI where I am porting the Win32 sample code to decrypt a .rpmsg file. The first code instance referencing FileProfile class fails with a linker error FileProfile function is undefined.
This line of code is fine in the IDE:
FileProfile::LoadAsync(profileSettings, loadPromise);

When building the app, the below error is given:

ld: error: undefined symbol: mipns::FileProfile::LoadAsync(mipns::FileProfile::Settings const&, std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<void> const&)

The header files defining the classes exist in the MIP SDK download so I assumed the classes would be included in the library. Did I do something wrong while porting the code to Android? Dumping the symbols from the Android library file libmip_unified.so, it does not contain symbols for the classes FileProfile, FileHandler, nor FileEngine. This applies to all libraries in the different ABI folders. The class references will eventually be added to the Android code.
Will there be a future release of the MIP SDK for Android that includes the File* classes?

From MS documentation is stated that mobile MIP SDKs (Android or iOS) implement only Protection and Policies classes. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip. You need to unprotect the file by "manually" managing the decryption function for the data streams.
